# Using IO::Socket::SSL over an IO::Socket::SOCKS proxy

Tags: perl, ssl, socks

I'd like to mix SSL and SOCKS sockets. In other words, I want to send TLS encrypted data over a SOCKS proxy and I'd like to use IO::Socket::SSL and IO::Socket::Socks

The only option I can think of is to duplicate IO::Socket::SSL into an IO::Socket::SocksSSL class that inherit from IO::Socket::Socks. That's the only way to have the right order for (eg send). I need first to have the SSL method invoked and then it will invoke the parent (IO::Socket::Socks) send. Same for connect where the SSL connect would invoke the Socks connect and then start the TLS negotiation.

Unfortunately, the IO::Socket::SSL does not have a $SOCKET_CLASS var that would allow a subclass to easily decide what it inherits from, so I to change that one line in SSL.pm and duplicate all the code

I'm probably missing something here

Comment: Maybe https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::Socks::Wrapper will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a SOCKS proxy for TCP (and thus SSL) essentially means to first create a TCP socket, do some initial SOCKS handshake and then continue to work with the socket like with a normal TCP socket. `IO::Socket::Socks->new(...)` does this initial SOCKS handshake and returns a normal TCP socket. `IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($socket,...)` then does the TLS handshake on this socket. Combining both essentially does the same as `IO::Socket::SSL->new(...)`, only using a SOCKS proxy instead of a direct connection.

Thus the code might look something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::Socks;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

# establish TCP connection to target via SOCKS proxy
my $cl = IO::Socket::Socks->new(
    ProxyAddr => '127.0.0.1',
    ProxyPort => 1234,
    ConnectAddr => 'whatsmyip.net',
    ConnectPort => 443
) or die $!;

# upgrade the TCP socket to TLS
IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($cl,
    # hostname is needed for SNI and certificate validation
    SSL_hostname => 'whatsmyip.net'
) or die $SSL_ERROR;

# do a simple HTTP request on it
print $cl "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: whatsmyip.net\r\n\r\n";
print <$cl>;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. What I fail to understand is once the start_SSL has happened, the object become blessed "IO::Socket::SSL", so all the methods of the original objects are unaccessible, right?
So, when a send() is called on the $cl, it will call IO::Socket::SSL::send() which will do the ciphering and then call its parents's send, which will be IO::Socket::INET::send (at least in ipv4). But that's not what we want, no? We want that call to call IO::Socket::Socks::send so that the SOCKS header is added and the encrypted packet is sent to the proxy.

Comment: @philippe_44: As I said, SOCKS is only an initial handshake on the TCP connection. After this SOCKS handshake there is nothing more, just plain TCP. Thus there is no need to continue to write on the SOCKS socket since writing to the underlying TCP socket is exactly the same.

Comment: @philippe_44: Or in other words: you could create an `IO::Socket::IP` object (or a plain AF_INET socket) and create a `socksify(socket)` function which just does the SOCKS handshake and then continue with the original socket.

Comment: @philippe_44: or in other words: you could create an `IO::Socket::IP` object (or a plain AF_INET socket) and create a `socksify(socket)` function which just does the SOCKS handshake and then continue with the original socket.

Comment: Oh, I ot it now. I was reading the IO::Socket::Socks::send code and saw that 

```sub send {
 my $self = shift;

 unless (defined ${*$self}->{SOCKS}->{TCP}) {
  return $self->SUPER::send(@_);
 }

``` and did not realize that it was only for UDP sockets